# Select with transparent background and white text causes options to be invisible in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-select

There seems to be an issue when using a select element with white text and transparent background in Chrome. It causes all options apart from the selected one to be invisible (white text on white background). How can I work around this?

[image]

Example:

```css
html, body {
  background: black;
}

select {
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It is not possible to have transparent `option` in most browsers.

Comment: Why not make the select background black (or the same as your body if that should ever be different).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just set different color to text inside select options

```css
html, body {
  background: black;
}

select {
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
}

#mySelect *{
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<select id='mySelect'>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```